# existence of a lifting

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I was asking myself if given a covering projection $p: X' \rightarrow X$ and a continuous map $f:Y \rightarrow X$, does a lift $f: Y \rightarrow X'$ always exists? If no, could you please exhibit a counterexample?

Comment: No, but there is a simple criterion in terms of the fundamental groups of the spaces and the induced maps $p_{\#}$ and $f_{\#}$ between them. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space#Lifting_properties

Comment: For a suitably well behaved space $Y$, the failure of this to hold in general is captured by the first (co)homology group of $Y$.  Loosely speaking, every singular simplex within $Y$ may be realized as a homotopy and so admits liftings by the homotopy lifting property.  But a cycle (simplex with no boundary) within $Y$ admits no lift in general, as in the example for $S^1$ given by Tsemo Aristide.

Answer (score 10):

No, consider the standard covering $p:R\rightarrow S^1$, and $f$ the identity of $S^1$. A lifting $g$ implies that $p\circ g$ is null homotopic so cannot be the identity.

Answer (score 2):

Generalizing the counterexample in the already existing answer, given any non-simply connected space $X$ and a loop $\gamma: S^1 \to X$ representing a nontrivial element of $\pi_1(X)$, $\gamma$ cannot be lifted to the universal cover $p : \tilde{X} \to X$ since otherwise it would be nullhomotopic in the cover, thus in the base.

However, if $p : \tilde{X} \to X$ is a covering map, $f : Y \to X$ a map such that $f_*(\pi_1(Y)) \subset p_*(\pi_1(\tilde{X}))$, then $f$ can be lifted to $\tilde{X}$ along $p$. This is known as the map lifting lemma.